# Java CLI-Application: Works in Netbeans, crashes on CLI

Tags: java, netbeans, version

I have created a simple Java CLI application. It uses a 3rd party lib which uses native code through JNI (swig). When using the "Run" function in Netbeans, the application runs perfectly fine and has acceptable performance.

The application reads a file, iterates over all records in it, performs a calculation and then writes an output file.

Now when I build the app and use it from the CLI (Win 7) the application starts and performs the calculation mostly for the first 3 records and then fails. Rarely it fails later and removing the 4th record does not change that, meaning the failure is not due to bad input or as missing link to native library. The crash is without error message, just the Java Dialog Box:

```
[Window Title]
Java(TM) Platform SE binary

[Main Instruction]
Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working

[Content]
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.

[Close the program]
```

Even more confusing is, that this did once work. I have rebooted at least once since then (friday). It could be an issue with windows settings or environment variables?

Windows Event Viewer says the following:

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 7.0.450.18, time stamp: 0x525404d0
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18205, time stamp: 0x51db96c5
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000c385b
Faulting process id: 0xd38
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceea75b763490c
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: fc71e0fd-5668-11e3-a3f1-083e8e9dc95b
```

Now I'm confused? How can I solve this issue? What is different in netbeans than on the cli?

Comment: `Exception code: 0xc0000374` indicates heap corruption.Solution may be available here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1081496